# How to use one UIView for Custom TableViewCell and CollectionView Cell.?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I want to create same `CustomCell` for `UICollectionView` and `UITableView`. But I don't want to create different CustomCells for this both.

So How can I use same `UIView` for this cells.?

I want to create following screens into my application.

[image]
[image]

Is there any solution for this.?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Create a custom View (xib). Let it param with object (for text, etc.). Add constraints to it. On your custom cells, add a subview (don't forget to set its class) to the contentView, add the constraints to leading/trailing/bottom/top to the contentView and that's it?

Comment: For your information we can add `UITableviewCell` as a subview to other views. Create one custom cell with specified layout and we can use it for running on UITableView and adding it as a subView to the UIView.

Answer (score 1):

Create a .xib file for your *CustomCell*,

then just initialise it in your respective classes like:

```
UICollectionView.dequeueReusableCell()
UITableView.dequeueReusableCell()
```

Answer (score 1):

When dequeueReusableCell of collectionView or tableview.
 1. Check if cell.contentView has subview of CustomView.
 2. If not, create object of CustomView class and add as subview to cell.contentView
3. Fill CustomView with data.